# If I fetch all remotes then where the FETCH_HEAD will be

Tags: git

Suppose I have 3 Remotes.

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:test/sample.git
git remote add upstream git@bitbucket.org:test/sample.git
git remote add new_remote git@personal.com:test/sample.git
```

If I run `git fetch --all`, where the `FETCH_HEAD` will be pointing to. I mean which remote will take the precedence.

Comment: `FETCH_HEAD` will record everything fetched. To select a particular commit from a particular repository, one must read the entire file and pick out the interesting line(s). (Note that you get the same kind of problem when using `git fetch --append` aka `git fetch -a`, but here the same repository and branch names may be mentioned multiple times.)

Comment: See, now, I'd have just made that an answer :-)

Comment: @torek if I use `git fetch origin master`, then what happens. Where is the `FETCH_HEAD` then?

Comment: It's in the same place as always (`.git/FETCH_HEAD`) and since you fetched one name from one remote/URL, it has one line in it (unless you used `-a` of course).